# How to multiple row div square pattern

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a pattern of 5 rows of div tags using for loops in javascript. The first row should have 1 div, the second 2 divs and so on until there the last row has 5 divs. What I currently end up with is 1 row of 15 divs.

```
<script>

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }

</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
    div {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;

        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: should not j need to go inside your p variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply consider `br` tag to create the separation and no need to use float because you will have to clear it after each row:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add('box');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(br);
}
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

With float you will need something like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add('box');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(br);
}
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float:left;
}
br {
 clear:both; /*This is mandatory !!*/
}
```

Or like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var p = document.createElement("div"); /*Create the row*/
  p.classList.add('clear'); /*add the clear class*/
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add('box');
    p.appendChild(div); /*Append blocks to the row and not the body*/
  }
  document.body.appendChild(p); /*Append the row to the body */
}
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float:left;
}
div.clear {
 clear:both; /*This is mandatory !!*/
}
```